# How to add prefix and suffix to a string in python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,re
import subprocess

def funa():
        a = str(raw_input('Enter your choice [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]: ')).upper().strip()
        p = re.compile(r'.*'+a+'.*')
        result = p.findall(a)
        str1 = ''.join(result)
        print str1
funa()
```

I have above code in test.py file and When I run this code and give my choice as SECONDARY, I am getting the output SECONDARY as string:

`[oracle@localhost oracle]$ ./test.py
Enter your choice [PRIMARY|SECONDARY]: SECONDARY
SECONDARY`

I want to add prefix as '^' and suffix as '$' to add in my output. Which should be a string only. Means I want to get the output as :

**^SECONDARY$**

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: You are already using `+` on strings earlier in your function. What is it you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can concatenate those onto the string using +.

For example (for Python 2):

```
print "^"+str1+"$"
```

Or without + using f-strings in Python 3:

```
print( f“^{str}$” )
```

Or if you want to add a prefix to every string in a list:

```
strings = ['hello', 1, 'bye']
decoratedstrings = [f"^{s}$" for s in strings]
```

result:

```
['^hello$', '^1$', '^bye$']
```

Comment: @barny thanks it worked for me. Not sure why its downgrade.

Comment: Though I did not downvote, I guess the downvoter expects a bit of explanation about the code, something other than *try this*.

Answer (score 1):

Bit out of context but can be helpful for people like me.

If a string list then,

```
strString = map(lambda x: '^' + x + '$', strString)
```

The resultant will be string list as well with prefix and suffix added to each string element of the list.

Comment: Rather than `map()` and `lambda`, wouldn't it be simpler to use a comprehension like `strings=[f"^{s}$" for s in strings]`?